# Implementing Decimal/arbitrary arithmetic using integer-like data types

Tags: integer, decimal, arbitrary-precision

This probably has probably been asked before, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Would it be possible/performant to implement a kind of arbitrary/decimal arithmatic through a specialized class or struct of an arbitrary/fixed amount of integers?

Let me clarify; floats (as I understand them), use a mantissa, exponent and perhaps a sign bit. They are capable of representing 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc... but not, say 1/10.

What I propose is something like this: let the number be represented by a plain `int` or `int64_t` or a series of these, keeping only the values up to a power of ten completely covered by the range of the integer (so for a 32-bit int, the limit would be 10^8-1). This only to keep calculation easy. Add to that an exponent, that will say what power of ten it should be multiplied to get the real number.

An example: 125.36 would be represented by an `int` equal to 12536 and a power of ten equal to -2. This number would in effect take as much as too `int`s, and a bunch of special functions.

Another example: 4,294,967,297 (which is 2^32+1) would take two `int`s, one equal to 4, the other equal to 294,967,297, and a power of ten equal to 0.

Is this a good idea, throwing away all this memory for a simpler/faster arithmetic? I haven't quite thought out the overflow part, perhaps calculating `int32_t+int32_t=int64_t` would solve that beautifully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [General Decimal Arithmetic](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/) page

Answer (score 0):

You are pondering on the precision limitations of binary arithmetic. I think that trading binary precision for decimal precision won't bring you anywhere.

You are right, binary can represent 1/2 and 1/4, but not 1/10, which decimal can. But both of them cannot represent 1/3. So there always will be some limitation of precision. (It may be hidden for decimal calculations, since we get most data in real life in decimal format, that means that most real life data are rounded to any number decimal places.)

That said, you can look at [python Decimal package](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) (if python is your language), which implemented the behaviour, that you seem to intend: calculate decimal math the way we learned at school with "as needed" precision.

Comment: Yes, good point, but won't my scheme be able to get more precision than plain `double` or even `long double`, with possibly decent performance without much overhead? Or am I rethinking existing solutions which are much, much better?

Comment: Well, I'm certainly no expert in this realm. What is your aim? Speed - then take usual floating point operations; todays cpu's are highly optimized for this kind of thing. Precision - then why does it have to be decimal? (Really, just my 2c, nothing to really count on.)